# Program not returning indexes

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, while-loop, append

This should return the indexes where the letter appears in the code, but all it does is ask for the letter and word. Can someone help me out? (I'm a beginner.)

```
##task 3
word = input("Enter word: ")
wrdlist = list(word)
wrdlen = len(wrdlist)
l = []
a = 0
char = input("Enter letter: ")
while wrdlen > a:
    if char == wrdlist[a]:
        l.append(a)
        a = a+1
        continue
    else:
        continue
if not l:
    print("none")
else:
    print(loclist)
```

Comment: No, you do not increment `a` in the `else` case.

Comment: Please take the time to read [ask] and the other links on that page.

Comment: Printing variable values and conditional test results is an easy debug tool - it shows you what is happening as the code executes.

Comment: Thank you, everyone! I fixed everything and now I'm implementing it into my hangman program

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue stems from never incrementing your counter: `a`
since `a = a+1` is in your `if char == wrdlist[a]` it will only increment your loop if that condition is true.

What you need to do is:

```
##task 3
word = input("Enter word: ")
wrdlist = list(word)
wrdlen = len(wrdlist)
l = []
a = 0
char = input("Enter letter: ")
while wrdlen > a:
    if char == wrdlist[a]:
        l.append(a)

    a = a+1
if not l:
    print("none")
else:
    print(l)
```

Notice you don't need an else statement, that is because you want the counter to increment regardless if `char` matches `wrdlist[a]`

Answer (score 0):

**The problem**: you forgot to **increment `a` in the `else` case**.

```
## task 3
word = input("Enter word: ")
wrdlist = list(word)
wrdlen = len(wrdlist)
l = []
a = 0
char = input("Enter letter: ")
while wrdlen > a:
    if char == wrdlist[a]:
        l.append(a)
        a = a+1
        continue
    else:
        a = a+1
        continue
if not l:
    print("none")
else:
    print(l)
```

But this is one of the many reasons why `for` loops are to prefer over `while` loops, since we can here use:

```
## task 3
word = input("Enter word: ")
wrdlist = list(word)
l = []
a = 0
char = input("Enter letter: ")
for a in range(len(word)):
    if char == wrdlist[a]:
        l.append(a)
if not l:
    print("none")
else:
    print(l)
```

Furthermore we can still improve it significantly, by using list comprehension:

```
## task 3
word = input("Enter word: ")
wrdlist = list(word)
l = []
a = 0
char = input("Enter letter: ")
l = [a for a in range(len(word)) if char == word[a]]
if not l:
    print("none")
else:
    print(l)
```

We can also remove the index retrieval `word[a]` by using `enumerate(..)`:

```
## task 3
word = input("Enter word: ")
wrdlist = list(word)
l = []
a = 0
char = input("Enter letter: ")
l = [ix for ix, wi in enumerate(word)) if char == wi]
if not l:
    print("none")
else:
    print(l)
```

Answer (score 0):

W is an index counter, l is the list to add the counter to when the letter is found in an index.

```
word = input("Enter word: ")
char = input('Enter letter: ')

w = 0
l = []
for _ in word:
    if _ == char:
        l.append(w)
    w+=1

print(l)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your program has the following shortcomings:

1. It may enter an infinite loop due to the incorrect combination of while condition and update of variable **a**. At any mis-matach with the input string, the code is going into infinite loop
2. **loclist** is not defined

Proper update of the control variable `a` like this

```
while wrdlen > a:
    if char == wrdlist[a]:
        l.append(a)
    a = a+1
```

Also, replace `loclist` with `l`

Assuming, you want to print the list of indices where a particular character occurred, the following scripts helps

```
word = input("Enter word: ")
char = input("Enter letter: ")
occurrences = [index for index in range(len(word)) if word[index] == char]
print(occurrences if occurrences else "none")
```